# 'Sharing failed, please try again.' error while trying to share image via whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I'm using a Samsung android 9 device to debug my app, however I noticed that While I try to share content with an image from my app to whatsapp, It does not work, rather a toast message 'Sharing failed, please try again.' is shown.

When I try to share only text, it all works fine. However the moment I add an image uri as an intent extra, it toast an error. What could be the possible cause and solution?

Here is the code for sharing content to whatsapp

```
if(resultImage.exists()){

   Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resultImage.getAbsolutePath());

   Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent();
   whatsappIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
   whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Extra text");
   whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
   Uri.parse(resultImage.getAbsolutePath()));
   whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

   whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "Share Image to"));

}
```

PS: I am yet to try this code in other devices

Comment: In other device it works ?

Comment: Not yet. The problem is not the device. I have tried to share to whatsapp with other apps and it worked just fine

Comment: To solve this problem, just clear the App Cache and Data. You can do it by going to "Settings > Apps > Find Whatsapp > And then tapping on Clear Data."

Comment: @PriyaVasoya, I just tried your solution, it did not work.